# соотнесение родителей к ребенку

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Сын князя А и такой-то дамы?
Сын князя А от такой-то дамы?

Как правильно

Comment: Если сын, то "от", а если дочка - то "и". Шучу, просто с бывшими любят все делить и не говорят И, а говорят От, потому что князь ушёл "от".

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, "от" используется в таких случаях по отношению к мужчине, а не к женщине: *Сын какой-то дамы от князя А.*
Поэтому в вашем случае верным будет, полагаю, только вариант *Сын князя А и такой-то дамы.*

Comment: "Мой сын от первой жены" - стандартное употребление

Comment: @user190920 не встречал такого словоупотребления. "От первого брака" - да, "от первой жены" - нет.  Но посмотрел в Нацкорпусе - да, используемое (и нередко) словосочетание.

Answer (score 1):

Биологически это эквивалентно: сын ♂А и/от ♀Б.
Но есть стилистические и контекстные различия указания на один и тот же факт. Стилистика вопроса намекает на исторический дореволюционный контекст. Если это так, то:

1. Если дама текущая и единственная жена князя, то И лучше, чем ОТ.
2. Если дама любовница князя или изнасилована им (например, по праву первой ночи), то для подчеркивания распущенности князя предпочтительнее ОТ. С намеком , что у князя есть и еще множество бастардов.